# useSWR with optimisticData - Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, swr

I am using the new optimisticData feature of useSWR as follows:

```
const { data, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR<IUser | undefined>(`/api/user`, () => apiClient.user.userGet())
```

and further down in a function I try to mutate the user data:

```
 mutate(
     apiClient.user.userUpdate({
         userUpdateRequest: {
               name: value,
         }
     }),
     {
          optimisticData: {
          ...data,
          name: value,
     },
          populateCache: false,
     }
 )
```

apiClient.user.userUpdate is a function generated by openapi and has this signature:

```
/**
 * Update user fields
 */
async userUpdate(requestParameters: UserUpdateOperationRequest = {}, initOverrides?: RequestInit | runtime.InitOverrideFunction): Promise<void> {
    await this.userUpdateRaw(requestParameters, initOverrides);
}
```

Although the code works fine, it does generate the following Typescript error which I cannot get rid of:

> Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUser | Promise<IUser | undefined> | MutatorCallback<IUser | undefined> | undefined'.
> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IUser | undefined>'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IUser | undefined'.

We are using ReactNative. Any ideas?